# Function that can identify certain texts

Tags: php, function

Here's my problem. I'll try to keep it concise:

I have a wab page that displays the texts in the selected language like this:

> `<p><?php echo $langFile->data->message; ?></p>`

The actual text can look like this:

> *Hello, %1. You have %2 orders. If you %forgot% your password click %here% !*

So I have to write a function that can replace (called one time for each replacement) the %1 and %2 with certain texts, and the words between *%* to be replaced with a link text. The reason it's tricky is that I can have texts that look like this:

> Bla bla %1, bla ***%yada yada %2 yada%*** bla bla bla.

So here, the function has to replace ***%yada yada %2 yada%*** with a linkable text and, when called again, can replace %2 with another text.

I'm kind of new with programming, so I could use some pointers since I don't know how to get where I want if even possible. Thanks a lot in advance.

Regards

Comment: [What you have tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: I'd use `sprintf`... (And appropriate modifiers in the lang string)

Comment: I can't figure out if it's even doable.. or if I have to find another way of marking the texts I want to change in order to make such a function possible... I'm a bit lost

Comment: why not make everything require being wrapped in %. it looks like only your vars are strictly numeric and your machine tags would likely be a limited list.

Comment: Please post the function code. That way we could help you =)

Comment: @bwoebi I can't use it since in some languages the texts can have different formes. In one language it can look like this: **..%bla bla %1 bla bla%** and the same text in another language can look like: ..%1..%bla bla bla bla%

Comment: Do you have control over the templates? The use of spaces in your identifiers leads to all sorts of problems.

Comment: @Kapn0batai There exists a position specifier: `sprintf("Number 2: %d$2 and Number 1: %d$1", 10, 25);` outputs `Number 2: 25 and Number 1: 10`

Comment: @GeorgeCummins I only have control over the way I mark the parts I want to replace (the use of %). I can't control the input format if by that you mean the way the words are ordered since they're in many different languages.

Comment: What's the name of the system you're using?

Comment: I would replace `%[0-9]` with a token temporarily, to be parsed later (ie. `%yadda TOKEN_2 yadda%`).

Answer (score 1):

```
$whatever = explode('%', $something);
```

Then run through it like any other array. If you can find a common denominator and explode it, you can usually get any puzzle of regex or if/then to work how you need. The logic practically reveals itself afterwards.

As an example, I tried to find a way to guarantee removal of ALL script tags. Honestly, no one's regex worked. Then, I found the common denominator in html that I can use. I came up with this. It will guarantee to strip all script tags. Of course, it's only this simple with script tags because they won't be nested. However, it's a great example of how to use "exploding logic" or "accordion coding" to get your mind wrapped around the problem and make it happen.

```
$h = explode('>', $html);

foreach($h as $k => $v){
    $v = trim($v);
    if(preg_match('/^(<script[.*]*)/ius', $v)){
        $counter = $k;//starting key of the script stored for later
        }elseif(preg_match('/([.*]*<\/script$)/ius', $v)){
            $script = $k - $counter;//difference between opening and closing tag
            $counter = 0;//reset counter for next script
            for($i = $script; $i >= 0; $i--){//now use the keys to empty everything in between
                $h[$k-$i] = '';
                }
            }           
        }
for($i = 0; $i <= count($h); $i++){
    if($h[$i] != ''){
        $ht[$i] = $h[$i];//clean out the blanks so when we implode it works right.
        }
    }
$html = implode('> ', $ht);//all scripts stripped.GUARANTEED
```

I believe you can use this same idea with what you are trying to do. Though your internal statements will vary, but you will begin to see how it can flow more easily and actually show progress on what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using `%` you can use string variables in the text (unless you're writing some sort of a dynamic thing that will allow people to add their own vars like a CMS). You would make the variables come out of a database or something like that for the different languages. Example:

```
$name = 'Bob';
$salutation = "Hello, $name.";
$order_count = '2';
if ($order_count == '1'){
  $ordertext = "You have $order_count order.";
} else{
  $ordertext = "You have $order_count orders.";
} 
$forgot = 'forgot';
$link = 'http://www.domain.com/reset/password';
$forgotphrase = "If you $forgot your password click <a href='$link'>here</a>!";

$message = $salutation.$ordertext.$forgotphrase;
```

**Output**

```
Hello, Bob. You have 2 orders. If you forgot your password click here!
```

**Update**

To do this on a larger scale you could have a database table called 'phrasing'.

```
id,salutation,ordertext_plur,ordertext_sing,forgot,link,forgotphrase,language,updated
```

So in MySQL might look like this:

```
1,
'Hello, $name.',
'You have $order_count orders.',
'You have $order_count order.',
'forgot',
'http://www.domain.com/reset/password/en',
'If you $forgot your password click <a href='$link'>here</a>!',
'EN',
'2013-04-23 00:00:00'
```

Your SQL statement would look like:

```
select * from phrasing where language='EN';
```

Then you would assign the appropriate vars based on the output. You would have to give more thought to how you would implement this and how large the database should be.

**Other thoughts** You might consider using something like the [Google Translate Gadget](http://www.gmodules.com/ig/creator?synd=open&url=http://www.google.com/ig/modules/translatemypage.xml&lang=en) on your pages to translate the HTML code, instead of hard-coding translations into the database. Their database of translations is updated daily. Some of my large international clients use it instead of paying the money to translate into every language. Also it makes it easier to make changes to the code in one language without having to worry about missing it in others.

Comment: This would mean I have to have a separate var for every word in every language, since the phrasing can change, and that is what I have to solve.

Comment: No, you would have a separate phrase in every language. You would have vars in the code that you store in the database. `$ordertext` in English would be different than it would be in Spanish.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `preg_replace` http://php.net/manual/es/function.preg-replace.php

May be `%[1-9]` for the `%1`, `%2`, `%3` and `%[A-Za-z ]+%` for the other.

**There is something important...** You should change the % to any other caracter for one of the cases... that make easier the search, because...

This case is easy: `Hello, %1. You have %2 orders. If you %forgot% your password click %here% !`
This is not: `Bla bla %1, bla %yada yada %2 yada% bla bla bla.`
But this, for example is easier: `Bla bla #1, bla %yada yada #2 yada% bla bla bla.`